# Universal App: Should I extract shared Views to their own storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I have an universal App with two storyboards:

- `iPhone.storyboard`
- `iPad.storyboard`

Now I have views or "view-trees" that are present in both the iPad and iPhone. Should I create a "`Universal.storyboard`" (Is this even possible) or should I rather exclude those views to `nib`s and do it "the old way" and then reference those `UIViewController`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either or, it's really just a matter of opinion on wether or not your wish to use storyboards. If you do choose to use storyboards, you will have to make separate ones for iPads and iPhones. Even using storyboard you'll still end up using a bunch of userIdiom ifs if you plan on using the same view controller for iPhone and the iPad counterparts.

Comment: Well, I am already using storyboards, my question is more if I can use _another_ storyboard with UI used for both devices.

Comment: @Besi Do you mean 1 storyboard for both iPhone and iPad?

Comment: No. One for iPad and one for iPhone + an additional with "shared" views. Do you know what I mean. If that is not possible I will put the "shared" views in nibs so I can re-use them universally.

Comment: @Besi I've never done that, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can share a storyboard between the two platforms because when storyboards are created you have to define them as one or the other.

You can use a utility storyboard to hold things you want to access directly via code and not via segue - say something you wanted to share easily between applications like login, or utility views.  However it is still limited to one device platform or the other.

just for reference, if you add an identifier to your storyboard object, you can get it like this in code:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginPage"];

//once you have the view controller you can push it, pop it or segue to it.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

A neat trick that I picked up when converting iphone apps to iPad was just copy/paste iphone views from the iPhone storyboard into the iPad storyboard then display them using a popover.

The neat trick is this - before you do anything, set the size property on the iPhone viewcontroller to free form, then select it and command C to copy it.  Go to your iPad storyboard and paste it in and it will maintain its size.  Now you can use it however you want.  copy the objects off it or leave it as is.  This can save lots of time and frustration because normal copy/pasted converts the iphone view to big iPad views and then you have to fix them up.

Some pages can have a nice effect staying the exact same size and just being presented in a popover on the iPad without any changes.

hope that helps
be well